# ImportError: libIex.so.25 : cannot open shared object file- with OpenEXR

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-installation, python

I want to install and import the OpenEXR package in python to read some `.exr` files.
I installed the package using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenexr-dev
sudo apt-get install openexr
pip install OpenEXR
```

When I import the package in python, it throws up the following error:

> ImportError: libIex.so.25 : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried some solutions like,

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```

found at https://itsfoss.com/solve-open-shared-object-file-quick-tip/

but dint work.

How to solve this problem? My ubuntu version is 18.04 and python 3.6.10

Answer (score 1):

You can enter this directory:  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
run command:
`ls -l | grep libIex*`
Generally, the corresponding file libIex* can be found, for example, there may exist a file named  `libIex-2_2.so.12.0.0`

Then create a symbolic link:
`sudo ln -s ./libIex-2_2.so.12.0.0 ./libIex.so.25`

Comment: Any idea how to get python or the pip openexr package to use the correct libIex version/file instead..?